# Discord.js Send a message to a specific channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanted to make a poll command but I can't get it to send a message to a specific channel
This is my code:

```js
const { tprefix, pollchannel } = require('../config.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
 name: 'poll',
 description: 'can make polls',
 cooldown: 5,
 usage: '[ask] [emoji1] [emoji 2]',
 aliases: ['createpoll'],
 async execute(message) {
  const channel = message.client.channels.fetch(pollchannel);
  message.channel.send('you have 60 seconds.');

  // await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 60000));
  channel.client.send(`${tprefix} message`);
  message.channel.send('finished');
 },
};
```

It should send a message with "you have 60 seconds.", then wait 60 seconds and then send a message in the poll channel and on the current channel. The channel id is correct and written down in the config.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```js
const channel = message.client.channels.cache.get(pollchannel)
channel.send('hello')
```

---

- [`ChannelManager` Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager)
- [`Map.prototype.get` Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get)

Comment: Now I get this error:
TypeError: channel.client.send is not a function

Comment: Just use `channel.send`, not `channel.client.send`